# discord.py channel.send AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Ok so, I've got code like this:

```
# bot.py
import os
import sched
import time
import discord
import datetime

from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

import Library

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('discordToken')

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Question')
client = discord.Client()
lastEmbed = None
# s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
channelId = 692724253237313576
channelId = 765541418701684736
channel = client.get_channel(channelId)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channelId = 765541418701684736
    channel = client.get_channel(channelId)
    print(f'{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!')
    await channel.send(self.client.get_channel(channelId), "And what")
```

And I have problem with the last part:

```
await channel.send(self.client.get_channel(channelId), "And what")
```

I tried loads of different solutions but every time it throws exactly the same exception:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grzes\PycharmProjects\CoronaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/grzes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/bot.py", line 57, in on_ready
    await channel.send(self.client.get_channel(channelId), "And what")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
```

Comment: Use an integer for channelId and make sure it exists.

Comment: @MarcSances tried it, but nothing has changed, and I've checked, channel ids exist

Comment: Are you passing the secret token of your bot in the ``discord.Client()`` instruction? Did you invite the bot to the server of which channel you're trying to access? Are you sure the bot can access and send messages in such channel?

Comment: I just need client.run(TOKEN) at the end, right @MarcSances, or something else?

Comment: yes, sorry, ``client.run(TOKEN)``. But make sure the bot is present in your channel and double-check the channel ID and the bot permissions.

Comment: @MarcSances yeah, so I forgot about that part, although  I still have the same error, pasted channel ID once again, and the bot has administrator permission, so I bet it's more then enough.

Comment: Your send line should just be `await channel.send("And what")`

Answer (score 0):

When you're using member, channel, guild, role ids, you need them in integer type not string. You just have to change `channelId = "765541418701684736"` to `channelId = 765541418701684736`

Comment: Tried it, and outcome is identical

Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\grzes\PycharmProjects\CoronaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/grzes/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/bot.py", line 57, in on_ready
    await channel.send(self.client.get_channel(channelId), "And what")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: Is the channel id real, are you sure about that?

Answer (score 0):

You are not in any class, therefor `self` does not exist and is of type `NoneType`.
Simply removing the `self.` before `client` in the last line will fix the error that you are getting.

You also can't get a channel before logging in, so you should move that line into the `on_ready` event.

Assuming all channel IDs you provided are correct then the code should work. If no channel with a specified channel ID can be found the method `client.get_channel(channel_id: int)` will return None, so you should add some checks later on, if you try to scale things up.

Comment: I keep looking back at the original question and each time I find a new minor mistake. don't have to provide a channel as the first argument in `channel.send`, the `content` argument is the only one you need to send text to a channel.